# How to identify a specific word (like C Keyword) from an input text file and output them into an another external text file one word per line?

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, ifstream, lexical-analysis

I want to extract c-keywords from my given input text file (which is a sample c code) and output them into a separate text file one word per line. How can i get this? Please help me. My code is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

ifstream My_input_file("D:\\input.txt");
ofstream My_output_file("D:\\output.txt");
string line, temp;
int flag=1;
if(My_input_file.is_open())
{
    while(getline(My_input_file,line))
    {
        int lenth=line.length(),i;
        char* newline = new char[lenth+1];
        strcpy(newline,line.c_str());
        for(i=0; i<lenth; i++)
        {
            if(newline[i]=='/'&& newline[i+1]=='/')
                break;
            if (newline[i]=='/'&& newline[i+1]=='*')
                flag=2;
            if (newline[i]=='*'&& newline[i+1]=='/')
                {flag=1;
                i++;}
            else if(flag==1)
            My_output_file<<newline[i];
        }
        My_output_file<<"\n";

        for(i=0;i<lenth;i++)
        {
            if(newline[i]=' ')
            {
                if(temp=="auto"||temp=="double"||temp=="int"||temp=="struct"||temp=="break"||temp=="else"||temp=="long"||temp=="switch"||temp=="case"||temp=="enum"||temp=="register"||temp=="typedef"||temp=="char"||temp=="extern"||temp=="return"||temp=="union"||temp=="const"||temp=="float"||temp=="short"||temp=="unsigned"||temp=="continue"||temp=="for"||temp=="signed"||temp=="void"||temp=="default"||temp=="goto"||temp=="sizeof"||temp=="volatile"||temp=="do"||temp=="if"||temp=="static"||temp=="while")
                My_output_file<<newline[i];
            }
            else
            {
                temp+=newline[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

I want to extract the c keyword like word from my input text file and generate the matching word in a output text file. But my program just avoiding comment line. It does not write the matched word what i searched for.

If my input.txt file contains some text like a c++ code for prime number check with comment line

Then output.txt file should be look like:

The Whole prime number code Without comment line

Matched keyword list is:
Int
float
double
return

After editing my code i have find out a solution for lexical analysis. The edited code is looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
using namespace std;

int isKeyword(char buffer[]){
char keywords[32][10] = {"auto","break","case","char","const","continue","default",
                        "do","double","else","enum","extern","float","for","goto",
                        "if","int","long","register","return","short","signed",
                        "sizeof","static","struct","switch","typedef","union",
                        "unsigned","void","volatile","while"};
int i, flag = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 32; ++i){
    if(strcmp(keywords[i], buffer) == 0){
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
 }

return flag;
}

int main()
{

ifstream My_input_file("D:\\input.txt");
ifstream My_library_file("D:\\library.txt");
ofstream My_output_file("D:\\output.txt");
string line, temp;
int flag=1;
if(My_input_file.is_open())
{
while(getline(My_input_file,line))
{
    int lenth=line.length(),i;
    char* newline = new char[lenth+1];
    strcpy(newline,line.c_str());
    for(i=0; i<lenth; i++)
    {
        if(newline[i]=='/'&& newline[i+1]=='/')
            break;
        if (newline[i]=='/'&& newline[i+1]=='*')
            flag=2;
        if (newline[i]=='*'&& newline[i+1]=='/')
            {flag=1;
            i++;}
        else if(flag==1)
        My_output_file<<newline[i];
    }
    My_output_file<<"\n";
 }
 My_output_file<<endl<<"Keywords Found in Your Text";
 My_output_file<<endl<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
 cout<<"Keyword Found in Your Text"<<endl;
 cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
 char ch, buffer[15];
 ifstream fin("D:\\input.txt");
 int j=0;

 if(!fin.is_open()){
    cout<<"error while opening the file\n";
    exit(0);
 }

 while(!fin.eof()){
    ch = fin.get();

    if(isalnum(ch)){
        buffer[j++] = ch;
    }
    else if((ch == ' ' || ch == '\n') && (j != 0)){
            buffer[j] = '\0';
            j = 0;

            if(isKeyword(buffer) == 1)
                cout<<buffer<<"\n";
    }

    }
   }
   return 0;
   }
```

But now it is output a text file without comment line and the founded keyword list in a console window. I want to output the keyword list in my output.txt file.

My input.txt is like this:
[input.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uNeI.jpg)

My Output Should be look like this:
[output.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olDNJ.jpg)

But it output a text file like this:
[After Clicking Build and Run the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CifSv.jpg)

and the console showing the founded keyword list like this:
[After Build and Run the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G60C0.jpg)

But, I want to put the founded keyword list into output.txt file instead of the console display.

Then i have changed these code:

```
if(isKeyword(buffer) == 1)
```

> cout<<buffer<<"\n";
> with this

```
My_output_file<<buffer[j]<<"\n";
```

Then i got my solution near about. But it output the first word of the keyword. How can i get the full word?

Comment: And what's wrong with your code? Please ask a specific question.

Comment: First thing you should do is to not create a copy of the input line, especially since you leak it each line. Secondly, this is actually a good use-case for regular expressions.

Comment: it seems like you are trying to perform a lexical analysis. Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(lexical_analyser_generator)?

Comment: Instead of a comment, please edit the question to describe clearly what the issue is with your code.

Comment: Anybody please help me.